# BLE is infinite loop stuck on running model

Tags: c++, c, tensorflow, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I was following this [tutorial](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/zoromoth/machine-learning-with-nano-ble-33-raspberry-pi-958b2f) of Arduino BLE 33 Sense to use it like a controler of Street Fighter on Raspberry Pi, I tried to use the BLE library to make it wireless with a baterry but I have problems running it like for two weeks, basically it get stuck on running the model I´m not sure if is because of the Bluetooth. Or something else but it don't show me the output from the gestures. It conects but after that it just show me on the serial monitor this:

```
Connecting ...

Connected
```

On my Python code that receives all the information, I tried with a this code line `txChar.writeValue(String(gestureid));` and it works but when I tried to use the model don't give me any result from the gestureid. These are the main lines that don't give me an output from the model:

```
gestureid=i+1; //THIS IS THE LINE THAT IS NOT WORKING
txChar.writeValue(String(gestureid));
Serial.print(txChar.writeValue(String(gestureid)));
```

Even when I tried to connect through BLE, it did hang up. But the reason is
simple... BLE library is a while loop that doesn't exit... Which means
execution never reaches the model code and the code too is an
infinite loop.

So I will have to create separate threads using <thread.h> library of C++
and then pass data between the threads.
But I'm not with to much experience on this so some documentation will be awesome or any advice.

I would be awesome if someone can help me with this.

[My full code](https://gist.github.com/fullmakeralchemist/b0a6c5211908dcb091b7dd70d32f6c31)

Part of the code that is not working:

```
void updateGyroscopeLevel() {
  
  float aX, aY, aZ, gX, gY, gZ;

  // check if new acceleration AND gyroscope data is available
  if (IMU.accelerationAvailable() && IMU.gyroscopeAvailable()) {
    // read the acceleration and gyroscope data
    IMU.readAcceleration(aX, aY, aZ);
    IMU.readGyroscope(gX, gY, gZ);

    // normalize the IMU data between 0 to 1 and store in the model's
    // input tensor
    tflInputTensor->data.f[samplesRead * 6 + 0] = (aX + 4.0) / 8.0;
    tflInputTensor->data.f[samplesRead * 6 + 1] = (aY + 4.0) / 8.0;
    tflInputTensor->data.f[samplesRead * 6 + 2] = (aZ + 4.0) / 8.0;
    tflInputTensor->data.f[samplesRead * 6 + 3] = (gX + 2000.0) / 4000.0;
    tflInputTensor->data.f[samplesRead * 6 + 4] = (gY + 2000.0) / 4000.0;
    tflInputTensor->data.f[samplesRead * 6 + 5] = (gZ + 2000.0) / 4000.0;

    samplesRead++;

    if (samplesRead == numSamples) {
      // Run inferencing
      TfLiteStatus invokeStatus = tflInterpreter->Invoke();
      if (invokeStatus != kTfLiteOk) {
        Serial.println("Invoke failed!");
        while (1);
        return;
      }

      // Loop through the output tensor values from the model
      for (int i = 0; i < NUM_GESTURES; i++) {
        if(tflOutputTensor->data.f[i]>0.7)
        {
          gestureid=i+1; //THIS IS THE LINE THAT IS NOT WORKING
          txChar.writeValue(String(gestureid));
          Serial.print(txChar.writeValue(String(gestureid)));
        }
      }

      Serial.print(gestureid);
      gestureid=0;
      //Serial.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: so `Connected to central:` is never printed to serial?

Comment: There is a lot of code in your question and it is not clear what is working and what is not.  You might want to look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Have you tested connecting to the Arduino with nRF Connect? Or on the Raspberry Pi you can use the Chromium browser with the URL `chrome://bluetooth-internals/#devices` to do the same. You have also created a custom characteristic in the [Bluetooth reserved range](https://www.novelbits.io/uuid-for-custom-services-and-characteristics/)

Comment: @M.Kotzjan I updated the post I hope is more clear about my problem.

Comment: @ukBaz I try to connect with nRF and it Connect but never receives data, but is because the model on the void updateGyroscopeLevel() is not running or yes but I'm not sure it didn't show me any error.

Comment: @Eduardomaker can you give us the log output as well?

Comment: @Eduardomaker I would be interested in the output of lines like `Serial.print("Disconnected from central: ");`

Comment: @M.Kotzjan that depends on the devide if you use nRF Connect it will give you the device Bluetooth address.